# Having problem in React-photoswipe-gallery, need to show only one photo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, mern

---

I'm try to implement react-photoswipe-gallery in my project but having problem to implement. as my UI I have to show only one photo in my project when user click on the photo the gallery should appear (`react-photoswipe-gallery pop`). try every thing but non of them work for me.

**This is my code for your refernce**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css";
import { Gallery, Item, useGallery } from "react-photoswipe-gallery";
// import useGallery from "react-photoswipe-gallery";

const MyGallery = () => {
  const { open } = useGallery();
  console.log(open);
  useEffect(() => {
    open(1); // you can open second slide by calling open(1) in useEffect
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <Gallery>
      <Item
        original="https://placekitten.com/1024/768?image=1"
        thumbnail="https://placekitten.com/80/60?image=1"
        width="100"
        height="100"
      >
        {({ ref, open }) => (
          <img
            ref={ref}
            onClick={open}
            width="100"
            height="100"
            src="https://placekitten.com/1024/768?image=1"
            alt="Kitten 1"
          />
        )}
      </Item>
      <Item
        original="https://placekitten.com/1024/768?image=2"
        thumbnail="https://placekitten.com/80/60?image=2"
        width="100"
        height="100"
        // onClick={handleItemClick}
      >
        {({ ref }) => (
          <div ref={ref}>
            {/* <img
              ref={ref}
              width="100"
              height="100"
              // src="https://placekitten.com/1024/768?image=2"
              alt="Kitten 2"
            /> */}
          </div>
        )}
      </Item>
      {/* Add more Item components for additional photos */}
    </Gallery>
  );
};

export default MyGallery;
```

**Example API response :**

```
const products = [
  {
    productName: 'Product 1',
    photos: [
      { src: 'https://example.com/photo1.jpg', w: 1024, h: 768 },
      { src: 'https://example.com/photo2.jpg', w: 1024, h: 768 },
      { src: 'https://example.com/photo3.png', w: 1024, h: 768 },
    ],
  },
  {
    productName: 'Product 2',
    photos: [
      { src: 'https://example.com/photo4.jpg', w: 1024, h: 768 },
      { src: 'https://example.com/photo5.jpg', w: 1024, h: 768 },
      { src: 'https://example.com/photo6.png', w: 1024, h: 768 },
    ],
  },
];
```

[Example output](https://codesandbox.io/embed/amazing-banach-nkfw8c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**`Note :`**`Check out link this how I want with my API response`